# Why does xcode's NSManagedObject generated subclasses miss methods for working with to-many relationships

Tags: xcode, core-data

In Xcode 8 Apple will update Xcodes abilities to generate NSManagedObject subclasses. But xcode will still not add methods for adding or removing objects to/from to-many relationships. Why is that? What am I missing. Does anyone know if this is deliberate from Apple, or just a missing piece of functionality?

Talking about swift generated subclasses. The obj-c version gets the methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly a bug. Right now we're at Xcode 8's first public beta, and bugs are expected. Please go to http://bugreport.apple.com/ and report it. I reported it (rdar://27071943 in case anyone from Apple sees this), but more reports mean that it's more likely to be fixed.

Comment: Ok Thanks! Have reported it as a bugg in the past.

Comment: Mogenerator is great while waiting though!